# Black screen after waking from suspend Ubuntu Budgie 18.10

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a Dell XPS 15 9570 with Ubuntu Budgie 18.10 installed on it. When I'm using the integrated graphics card from Intel (by issuing `sudo prime-select intel`) everything works smoothly, but when I select the NVIDIA dedicated graphics card (issuing `sudo prime-select nvidia`) I can't wake from suspend: when I re-open the lid after having closed it, the screen remains black. I can tell that the system actually woke up because the fan makes some noise and the keyboard's backlight works fine.

My dedicated graphics card is the Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050 Ti, and the driver version is 390.87

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with my Lenovo (also with NVidia graphics). When this happens I just use the key that increases the screen brightness to light up the screen (which is just set to brightness=0).

Answer (score 0):

Considering xenoid's example, it seems it may be a brightness problem, the computer might think it's a laptop, or something else that has a brightness setting.

EDIT: OH WAIT, IT IS A LAPTOP stupid me